# RestKit importing from JSON with foreign keys

Tags: ios, json, entity-framework, core-data, restkit

I currently have a number of entities in a `Core Data` database with a `Web API` back-end serving `JSON`. Each entity has a separate endpoint on the server which returns all of those entities in the database, e.g.

```
.../api/student
.../api/teacher
.../api/degree
etc
```

The `JSON` is serialised to include foreign key ids. Below is an example response for a student:

```
[
  {
    "studentID" : 1,
    "degree" : {
      "degreeID" : 1
    },
    "name" : "My Name",
    "teachers" : [
      { "teacherID" : 1 },
      { "teacherID" : 2 }
    ]
  }
]
```

The 'student, teacher, degree' design is a fictitious example and unfortunately the real database is more complex with lots of both '*one-to-many*' and '*many-to-many'* relationships.

I'm new to `RestKit` and not sure on the best way to request and process this data for Core Data. When the app launches, I simply need the app to update its `Core Data` database to match the `Web API` version. Any guidance on how best to request each endpoint and process the mappings would be much appreciated. Would I need to have already requested and stored the degrees and teachers before I could import the `JSON` above, for example? I have full control over both the client and the server.

**Edit: Added example code**

Below is some example code similar to mine. I have tried a number of different approaches (addRelationshipMappingWithSourceKeyPath and addConnectionForRelationship for example) to handle the 'to-many' relationship from students to teachers however I always seem to receive the following error:

```
relationship 'teachers' fault on managed object
```

Example code:

```
RKEntityMapping *studentMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"Student" inManagedObjectStore:managedObjectStore];

studentMapping.identificationAttributes = @[ @"id" ];

[studentMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{@"name" : @"name"}];

RKEntityMapping *teacherMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"Teacher" inManagedObjectStore:managedObjectStore];

tagMapping.identificationAttributes = @[ @"id" ];

[teacherMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{@"name" : @"name"}];

/*** RELATIONSHIP CONNECTION ***/

[studentMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"teachers" toKeyPath:@"id" withMapping:teacherMapping]];

/*** RESPONSE DESCRIPTORS ***/

RKResponseDescriptor *studentResponseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:studentMapping method:RKRequestMethodGET pathPattern:@"/api/student" keyPath:nil statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];

[objectManager addResponseDescriptor:studentResponseDescriptor];

RKResponseDescriptor *teacherResponseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:teacherMapping method:RKRequestMethodGET pathPattern:@"/api/teacher" keyPath:nil statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];

[objectManager addResponseDescriptor:teacherResponseDescriptor];
```

Comment: Each endpoint gives all details for one type and all relationships it has with only the id? And you want to call all endpoints when the app launches?

Comment: Yes. At the moment I have a separate endpoint for each type/entity. As I will need the Core Data database to match the server's version exactly, I believe I will need to call each endpoint in turn.

Comment: You wont be able to call them concurrently, but other than that you should have no issues. Look at other answers on foreign key mapping and fetch request blocks.

Comment: Will I need to call them in order, i.e. 'degrees' before 'students' in example above (because 'students' references 'degrees')? The database has some circular references which would make this tricky if not impossible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relationships will be made to existing objects when each response is processed. Objects that don't exist are ignored by default.

You can have multiple response descriptors to create stub objects so that relationships are created and then fill the objects details in later.

Generally, I would have a single request to get the structure / relationships for 'everything' with very minimal details and then fill in the details later as the user requests it.

Comment: Thanks @Wain - I've done some more research and it looks like the stubs approach would work perfectly. Unfortunately I'm having a bit of trouble with RestKit recognising the foreign key 'to-many' relationship. I've added some example code to the question if you would be kind enough to take a quick look? :-)

Comment: A fault isn't an error, it's just (potential) content which hasn't been loaded into memory (yet).